# I can't get MySQL56 service to start after I stopped it

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue on my server. I am running MySQL on Windows Server 2008 R2. I have done some changes to my.ini file so I had to restart the MySQL for the changes to take effect. and when I went to services and tried to start MySQL56 windows gives me this error:

> Windows could not start the MySQL56 service on Local Computer. Error
> 1067: The process terminated Unexpectedly.

I tried rebooting my server, and that did not work. I restored the changes that I made to my.ini and that did not work.

What can I do to bring MySQL back up?

Comment: Anything informative in your logs?

Comment: where would i find the logs for mysql?

Comment: Depends.  [Read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/error-log.html).

Comment: here is an error  InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. The Log file was full. I had open the my.ini file and increase the 
innodb_log_file_size variable.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the default log file size is now 50MB instead of the old 5MB.  If you were running with a log file size of 5MB, this was probably a bad bottleneck for you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue the other day. Try this, it should work!

1. Right click on **MySQL Notifier** -> **Actions** -> **Manage Monitored Items**
2. Highlight the **MySQL56** entry and click the **delete** button
3. Click the **add** button -> **windows service**
4. Scroll down and look for **MySQL56**
5. **Highlight** it and click **ok**